# Can we take stalks of morphisms of pre-sheaves in general categories?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Suppose we have a topological space $X$ and a pre-sheaf $\mathcal F$ over it. My question would be: Is it possible, when $\mathcal F$ is merely a pre-sheaf in an arbitrary category $\mathcal C$ (ie. a functor $\operatorname{Ouv}(X) \to \mathcal C$, $\operatorname{Ouv}(X)$ being the category of open sets of $X$ with morphisms all inclusions $V \subseteq U$), to define, whenever we also have another pre-sheaf $\mathcal G$ and a morphism of pre-sheaves $\phi: \mathcal F \to \mathcal G$, the morphism $\phi_x$ on stalks? Note that taking stalks works in general, and defining the morphism $\phi_x$ works whenever we have a category where we can just explicitly define the stalk as the object of equivalence classes with the eq. rel. being equality on small sets. But I would like a purely categorical way of doing this, and I'm stuck at finding one, whence I'd appreciate any aid.

Comment: The stalk functor on the category presheaves is given simply by composing sheafification with the stalk functor on the category sheaves. Is this all you were overlooking, or is there more to your question?

Comment: What exactly are the implicit assumptions on the "arbitrary" category $\mathcal{C}$ here? If there are really no assumptions at all, then what is the stalk?

Comment: The stalk can be defined as a certain filtered colimit, so it exists whenever you can take filtered colimits. More abstractly, it can be defined as the left adjoint to pushforward from a point, so it exists whenever suitable adjoint functor theorems apply.

Comment: @Hurkyl I would like to define the stalk functor (EDIT: In ptic. on functions!) in a setting that is as general as possible (of course, Mr. Qiachu Yuan's comment above gives some restrictions), so that the construction possibly does not use the specific form of the stalk (such as when we have abelian groups, when we have an explicit description of the stalk). (Of course, if all categories satisfying the necessary condition of the last comment, then I'd be satisfied by knowing that. But I doubt it, and probably there is some easy combinatorial counter-example.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I suppose that applying the left adjoint of a pushforward already gives the construction. (I'm not yet familiar with these concepts unfortunately.)

Comment: Well, if you have those filtered colimits, then functoriality follows really analogously to the classical set-valued case. And if you define the stalk to be the left-adjunction, then it is a functor by definition. Isn't it?